# Response.Buffer / Flush Doesn't Appear to be Working

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7

I've got a classic asp page that users Response.Buffer = True and Flush. On my local pc this page works absolutely fine.

I've uploaded the page to my web server and it doesn't work. The only thing I've been able to check is in IIS under ASP/Behaviour/Enable Buffering is True on both machines.

On the web server the script runs with a blank page for about 4 secs and then displays the page, ignoring the buffering code.

Is there any other setting that would prevent a script from buffering.

Comment: Do you receive any error message?

Comment: No, no error message, Page should show "please wait", search database, remove "please wait", display database result. 

On the live server I get blank screen and then 4 seconds later page shows database result.

As I said, works fine on my localhost pc. That's why I think something might be set wrong in IIS on the live server.

Comment: the default buffer limit on IIS 7 is 4Mb for classic asp. You can try both setting unlimited buffer limit or turning the buffer off. (is buffer ON  mandatory for your application?)

Comment: Doubling the limit to 8mb has fixed it.

Many Thanks

Comment: Sounds like your storing way too much information in the buffer before calling `Response.Flush`.

Comment: Im passing a postcode to the page which searches a street database, about 1.2 million records.

Answer (score 1):

I'll often use Response.Flush before I enter the loop and on [recordset].AbsolutePosition Mod 1000 = 0 just to keep things moving.